# XAMPP localhost returns object not found after installing Traq

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, issue-tracking

I have installed the Traq it is a PHP5+ and MySQL4+ based Project Tracking system. Traq is able to create the required tables in MySQL but on the run it also create a Login folder which is not getting created. After installation of Traq when i click on Login link i end up on the page saying **XAMPP localhost returns object not found**. I have also found that the **mod_rewrite** option is also enable in the apache server and php of xampp.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to rename the file htaccess.txt into .htaccess